# VIEWS - Dynamic select privileges

Tags: mysql-workbench

we're supposed to create dynamic SELECT privileges on a view for every user, using it's employee abbreviation (Mitarbeiterkuerzel).
But I'm not able to get it done.
In the end every user should be able to only select those values in all the columns where it's username euqals it's abbreviation.

```
USE IAF03_ByceDB;

DROP USER IF EXISTS 'heck.i'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'brater.w'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'budar.h'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'baer.s'@'localhost';
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS V_Bestellungen;


CREATE USER 'heck.i'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'brater.w'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'budar.h'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'baer.s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

CREATE VIEW V_Bestellungen AS
select k.KUN_NR, k.NACHNAME, k.VORNAME, A.TNR, A.BEZEICHNUNG, af.MENGE, at.BESTELLDATUM, a.VERKAUFSPREIS, af.MENGE * a.VERKAUFSPREIS AS 'Rechnungsbetrag', ANG_NR AS Sachbearbeiter, lower(concat(concat(concat(an.Nachname, '.'),substring(an.Vorname,1,1)), '@', 'localhost'))as MITARBEITERKUERZEL
    FROM AUFTRAGSPOSITIONEN af
INNER JOIN AUFTRAEGE at USING (AUFTRAGSNR)
INNER JOIN ARTIKEL a USING (TNR)
INNER JOIN KUNDEN k USING (KUN_NR)
INNER JOIN ANGESTELLTE an USING (ANG_NR);

GRANT SELECT
    ON iaf03_bycedb.V_Bestellungen
    TO 'heck.i'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got one solution and it works.

```
USE IAF03_ByceDB;

DROP USER IF EXISTS 'heck.i'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'brater.w'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'budar.h'@'localhost';
DROP USER IF EXISTS 'baer.s'@'localhost';
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS V_Bestellungen;


CREATE USER 'heck.i'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'brater.w'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'budar.h'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
CREATE USER 'baer.s'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

CREATE VIEW V_Bestellungen AS
SELECT k.KUN_NR, k.NACHNAME, k.VORNAME, A.TNR, A.BEZEICHNUNG, af.MENGE, at.BESTELLDATUM, a.VERKAUFSPREIS, af.MENGE * a.VERKAUFSPREIS AS 'Rechnungsbetrag', ANG_NR AS Sachbearbeiter
    FROM AUFTRAGSPOSITIONEN af
INNER JOIN AUFTRAEGE at USING (AUFTRAGSNR)
INNER JOIN ARTIKEL a USING (TNR)
INNER JOIN KUNDEN k USING (KUN_NR)
INNER JOIN ANGESTELLTE an USING (ANG_NR)
    WHERE user() = lower(concat(concat(concat(an.Nachname, '.'),substring(an.Vorname,1,1)), '@', 'localhost'));
    

GRANT SELECT
    ON iaf03_bycedb.V_Bestellungen
    TO 'heck.i'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT
    ON iaf03_bycedb.V_Bestellungen
    TO 'brater.w'@'localhost';
    
GRANT SELECT
    ON iaf03_bycedb.V_Bestellungen
    TO 'budar.h'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT
    ON iaf03_bycedb.V_Bestellungen
    TO 'baer.s'@'localhost';
    
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```